# AWS Open search requests sent via lambda time out

Tags: python, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, elastic-stack, opensearch

I am trying to index data being received by an API to an AWS open search domain(using elastic search 7.10), the following is the code for my lambda function

```
# Dependency imports
from jose import jwt

import json

from pymongo import MongoClient

import requests

from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

import os

import boto3


credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()

awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, 'us-east-1', 
'opensearchservice'
, session_token=credentials.token)

client=MongoClient('mongodb+srv://{}:{}@cluster0.66zot.mongodb.net/database? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority'.format(os.environ['DB_USER'],os.environ['DB_PASS']))

db=client.database

def lambda_handler(event, context):

   claims=jwt.get_unverified_claims(event['headers']['Authorization'])

   collection=db.messages

   messages=json.loads(event['body'])['messages']

   for message in messages:
      message['user']=claims['sub']

   collection.insert_many(messages)

   for i in range(len(messages)):
      messages[i]['_id']=str(messages[i]['_id'])

   headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}

   requests.post(os.environ['ELASTIC_HOST']+'/messages/_doc/_bulk? 
   refresh=true',auth=awsauth,headers=headers,json=messages)

   return {
      'statusCode':200,
      'body':json.dumps("success")
   }
```

for some unknown reason, the API gateway keeps timing out (i.e the elastic search request is not completing).

My API gateway and lambda timeouts are set to 28s just for more information.

I also tried using the official python client for elastic search but had no luck.

Edit:
On further investigation, I can see my AWS lambda is not able to connect to the elastic instance itself, so I am guessing it has something to do with access policies but I already whitelisted the CIDR block of the VPC in which the lambda is running.

Edit:
I am close but I am getting an error
AuthorizationException(403, '
{
"message": "The security token included in the request is invalid."
})

any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: did you find out why this was happening? I'm getting the same issue except I'm not even getting the 403